# Button not Aligning at Bottom of Browser with Absolute Positioning HTML CSS

Tags: html, css, css-position

I have an element (`<button id="foo">FAQ</button>`). I have css for that button that is:

```
#foo {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;/* I tried using other units */
    left: 0px;/* same thing here*/
}
```

The problem is that the element ends up at the bottom of the screen (not browser window like I'm trying to do), and when you scroll down, there it stays there. I'm using google chrome version 53.0.x. I tried it in Microsoft Edge, and the problem is still there. The button has no parent (besides body). Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**EDIT**

Screenshot:
[image: error screenshot]

I want to make the button show up when you scroll down to the bottom, and absolute positioning doesn't do it.
I can see that my question is not well understood, so I would like to make some distinctions that might help make my question easier to understand:

screen: visible part of the window (dependent of scrolling)
browser window: the entire webpage (independent of scrolling)

Comment: It's unclear what you mean by "screen" or "it stays there". It stays where exactly? A browser element only exists within the window and does not interact with the "screen" at all. You seem to be mixing concepts. Try adding a screenshot and your CSS code for HTML and BODY.

Comment: Can you just explain more by showing what you have implemented so far and what actually you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

It is not `position: absolute;` but `position: fixed;`.

[Check this out](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp) to understand the possible options and the differences between them:

> **absolute**  The element is positioned relative to its first positioned (not static) ancestor element
>
> **fixed**     The element is positioned relative to the browser window

Comment: When you scroll down, I want it to appear. I'll think about weather I actually prefer your solution to my original goal.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to get it to sticky to the bottom of the browser window as you scroll? If so, give it a fixed position (`position: fixed;` instead of `position: absolute;`). If you want to get it to appear above or below certain elements on the page as well, look into setting the elements' [z-index](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp).